# Exibir conteúdo somente após carregamento total da página

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Olá, eu tenho o seguinte trecho de código abaixo:

**Código**

```css
div#container{
 position:absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0px;
 left:0px;
 background-color: #eee;
 display: block;
}

div#loader{
 border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite; 
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 left:0px;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>PÁGINA LOAD</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen"/>
 <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <div id="loader"></div>
  <div id="content">
      <p>Exibir meu código PHP aqui após o carregamento total da página</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jsor/jcarousel/master/dist/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Este evendo é acionado após o carregamento da página
  $(window).on('load', function(){
    //Após a leitura da pagina o evento fadeOut do loader é acionado, esta com delay para ser perceptivo em ambiente fora do servidor.
    jQuery("#loader").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Objetivo**

Eu gostaria que o meu conteúdo PHP fosse exibido na tela somente após carregar 100% pois esse trecho PHP é um `select` no banco de dados que demora um bom tempo para exibir dando aspecto que a página não está respondendo.

**Problema**

O loader sempre é exibido junto ao conteúdo PHP, sendo assim ele só é exibido após a requisição finalizar. Tentei diversas formas antes de postar no fórum, se alguém puder mostrar um método que funcione será de grande ajuda!

Comment: O loader deve desaparecer somente quando o código PHP estiver inserido no HTML?

Comment: Creio que vc deverá usar Ajax para carregar apenas o conteúdo da div #content.

Comment: Exatamente @VictorCarnaval

Comment: Como posso fazer isto @Sam? Poderia me dar um exemplo por favor!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Ajax para carregar o conteúdo da div `#content`. Por ser assíncrono, o loader ficará visível até que o conteúdo seja carregado na div.

Faça o seguinte:

Esconda a div `#content` no seu CSS:

```
#content{
   display: none;
}
```

Crie um arquivo `.php` que irá retornar o HTML que será inserido na div. Esse arquivo `.php` será requisitado pelo Ajax. O mesmo código PHP que você colocou na div `#content` será o que você irá colocar no arquivo `.php`.

Então você chama o Ajax quando a página for carregada:

```
<script>
$(function(){

   $("#content").load("pagina.php", function(){

      $("#content").show(); // mostra a div
      $("#loader").fadeOut("slow");

   })

});
</script>
```

Após o Ajax retornar os dados para a div, o loader será ocultado no callback do Ajax.

A `pagina.php` é de onde virão os dados. Aí você coloca o nome que quiser (ex., `content.php` etc...). Nessa página é onde será processado o código PHP que será retornado.

> Talvez nem seja preciso ocultar a div `#content`, já que ela estará
>   vazia inicialmente. Se não quiser esconder, pode dispensar o CSS que coloquei acima
>   e apagar a linha `$("#content").show();`.

Comment: Excelente resposta @Sam, indica algum material para leitura sobre AJAX?

Comment: Tem vários no Google. Pesquise por "javascript ajax" que os primeiros resultados da busca terão bons materiais para ler.

Comment: beleza, obrigado pela força!